# Spring reactivemongo dynamic collection name by spel

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

We are using springboot 3.1.0 and mongo db. We are using spring web flux

I want to retrieve collection name by accessing to the reactor context.

What I wrote is the following

```
@Document(collection = "#{@resorceNameResolver.getCollectionNameFromReactiveCtx()}")
public class GenericDocument<T> {
    @MongoId(FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String pk;
    private T resource;
}
```

Now in my controller I wrote something like this:

```
return repository.save(elment).contextWrite(context -> {
   return context.put(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, "collection_name");
}).flatMap(saved -> {
   return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(saved));
});
```

As you can see I write in reactor context collection name

Now I wrote this spring component:

```
@Component
public class ResorceNameResolver {
  public String getCollectionNameFromReactiveCtx(){
   Mono<String> fromContext = Mono
    .deferContextual(Mono::just)
    .filter(contextView -> contextView.hasKey(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY))
    .map(contextView -> contextView.getOrDefault(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, RESOURCE_NAME_DEFAULT_NAME))
    .map(resourceName ->{
        return resourceName;
    });
   return null;
  }
}
```

My question is: is it possible to retrieve the collection name from the reactor context and let spring data reactive mongo to understand where to store the element? If it's possible.. how can I do?

Thank you

Angelo